# :radio and :checked not being passed to my var

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, coldfusion

I have several forms on my page that use the same function to process them. Everything has been working just dandy until I wanted to add a radio button form to enable/disable the record in the database.

I've got the page set up so that there's a hidden form near an element. User clicks the div and my script grabs the html of the element and puts it into a var, shows the form and dumps the html (var) into a textarea and hides the element. Make some changes, click submit, form submits, hides and re-shows the element with the new html (facebook style). No problem.

When I write the code to capture the radio button that is "checked" it works fine. But, if I change to the other radio button, the form isn't capturing the new value. What's up?

```
if (field == "disabled") {
            var txt = $('#disabled input[name="product_disabled"]:radio').val();
        } else {
            var txt = $(this).html();
        };
```

This captures the value, no problem...

But, in my form handler, this just takes the above info, not the new info from the form.

```
var newtxt = $('#disabled input[name="product_disabled"]:radio').val();
```

Very strange...

Here's the full jQuery

```
//Begin editing section - click handler on text shows the form//
$('[class^=edit_]').click(function(){
    var element = $(this).attr('class');
    var field = element.split('_')[1];
    if (field == "disabled") {
            var txt = approval;
        } else {
            var txt = $(this).html();
        };
    //var txt = $(this).html();
    //$('[class='+element+']').hide();
    $(this).hide();
    $('[id='+field+']').show();
    $('[class=product_'+field+']').val(txt);
    $('[class=product_'+field+']').focus();             
});
//Process the edit forms//
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).html());
    var element = $(this).attr('id');
    var newtxt = $(this + "input[name='product_disabled']:radio").val(); //$('[class=product_'+element+']').val();
    var product = pid;
    var productImage = imageUrl;
    var rb = $('#disabled input[name="product_disabled"]:radio').val();

    $.getJSON("cfc/editProduct.cfc?method=updateText&returnformat=json", 
                {column:element, id:product, updateText:newtxt, image:productImage },
                function(response) {
                    //Handle the result
                    if(response.MESSAGE == "success") {
                        $('form').hide();
                        $('[class=edit_'+element+']').show();
                        $('[class=edit_'+element+']').html(newtxt);
                    } else {
                        alert(response.MESSAGE);
                    }
                });
});
//End editing section//
```

Comment: Consider using `<div contenteditable></div>`

Comment: So you are moving text between a DIV and a TEXTAREA element and vice-versa. How is the value of a radio-button related to that?

Comment: In all the other places on my page, the text/html of the element is editable so it gets passed into the TEXTAREA so it can be edited. I'm trying to get my page to use the form processing script to process radio buttons but it's not listening to the radio button form for some reason. The processing script isn't picking up which radio button has been checked...

Comment: Could you give a (non-)working example?

Comment: @Ofeargall What do you mean by "process radio-button"?

Comment: Revised the post to include the full processing script...

Comment: When I say "process radio button" I mean that the script that is processing the other forms isn't picking up the values from the radio button form when that form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the first option was *empty* value, so I used this ( although it was for a select input )

```
$(this).val($(this + "option:first").val());
```

Comment: You mean `$(this).find('option:first').val()`?

Comment: I mean what I wrote, I pulled it straight from my script, which is functional ;)

Comment: @Kirk But `this` is a reference to an object (the SELECT object, I assume). You are concatenating `this` to a string, which means that `this` will be string-coerced to something like `[object Object]`. Therefore, the selector inside `$()` is `[object Object]option:first` which is invalid.

Comment: I'm sorry, but did you read what my answer was? "I had a similar issue" "so i used this" — I wanted to point in the right direction, this is not an absolute answer.

Comment: @All, As it turns out the trouble has NOTHING to do with my processing script and EVERYTHING to do with a variable that I set earlier on in my code. Because the radiobutton uses the same name, when I set the `var txt = approved` It set it for both radio button values. I'm sorry for any inconvenience.